# Black and white 3D scatterplot?

Tags: data-visualization, scatterplot

For any $i \in \{1,2,\ldots, 9801\}$, we have 3 dimensional vectors $\mathbf{a}_i$ and $\mathbf{b}_i$ that take values in $\mathbb{R}^3$, where $\mathbf{a}_i = (a_{i,1}, a_{i,2}, a_{i,3})$ and $\mathbf{b}_i = (b_{i,1}, b_{i,2}, b_{i,3})$.

For any $i$, the difference between the vectors $\mathbf{a}_i$ and $\mathbf{b}_i$ is that:

- For $\mathbf{a}_i$, the first two components are found empirically, but the third component $a_{i,3}$ is defined analytically as a function of the first two components $a_{i,1}$ and $a_{i,2}$. In other words, $\mathbf{a}_i = \big(a_{i,1}, a_{i,2}, f(a_{i,1}, a_{i,2})\big)$.
- But for $\mathbf{b}_i$, all of the components are found empirically.

For all $i \in \{1,2,\ldots, 9801\}$, the figure below depicts $\mathbf{a}_i$ by red dots, and $\mathbf{b}_i$ by black dots.

[image]

My problem here is that I am unhappy with the use of multiple colours as I have to stick to black and white for compatibility with non-colourful printers.

My question is: How can I distinguish these two surfaces using only black and white?

Other input:

- The number of dots are $9801 = 99 \times 99$ for each surface

Comment: Care you share the formula for a, to facilitate answers with examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to plot the two surfaces as:

- One surface is dark grey.
- The other is light grey.

Then add transparency to both of them.

The 3D mesh surface would imply that you are using linear interpolation for values of $\mathbf{a}_i,\mathbf{b}_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$ that do not exist in your set of $9801$ points. Is this a problem?

If that's not a problem, then I think your problem is solved (unless I am missing something).

If that is a problem, then you may try the same, but try to see if you can draw dots with transparency.